# gunicorn catch request but only one flask route is working

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Hi stackoverflow people,

I use `gunicorn` to deploy my `flask` app, here is my configuration file:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid user
setgid www-data

exec gunicorn  --log-level=DEBUG  --workers $(( 2 * `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id' | wc -l` + 1 )) --limit-request-line 0 --bind unix:my_app.sock --timeout=10 -m 007 main:app
```

I used this `gunicorn` file for several other projects, it always worked but this time it acts differently.

When I take a look in the log file, I can see my requests:

```
[29878] [DEBUG] GET /event
[28948] [DEBUG] GET /
```

But nothing happened.
Only one route is working, it's the one present in my main file

here is the file `main.py`:

```
from __init__ import app
from auth import authentification
from auth.authentification import auth
from route.route import api
from route.event import EventClass
from route.profile import Profile_route
from route.report import Report
from route.search import Search
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from extensions import db, mail, login_manager
from config import BaseConfig, DefaultConfig
from flask.ext.mail import Message
import base64, time, os
from werkzeug.serving import BaseRequestHandler
from flask_swagger import swagger

class MyFancyRequestHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    """Extend werkzeug request handler to suit our needs."""
    def handle(self):
        self.fancyStarted = time.time()
        rv = super(MyFancyRequestHandler, self).handle()
        return rv

    def send_response(self, *args, **kw):
        self.fancyProcessed = time.time()
        super(MyFancyRequestHandler, self).send_response(*args, **kw)

    def log_request(self, code='-', size='-'):
        duration = int((self.fancyProcessed - self.fancyStarted) * 1000)
        self.log('info', '"{0}" {1} {2} [{3}ms]'.format(self.requestline, code, size, duration))

DEFAULT_BLUEPRINTS = (
    auth,
    api
)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "This route is working !"

def configure_swagger(app):
    from flasgger import Swagger
    Swagger(app)


def configure_auth():
    authentification.Auth()

def configure_app(app):
    """Different ways of configurations."""

    if app.debug:
        # http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#configuration
        app.config.from_object(DefaultConfig)
    else:
        app.config.from_object(BaseConfig)

def configure_blueprints(app, blueprints):
    """Configure blueprints"""
    for blueprint in blueprints:
        app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

def configure_extensions(app):
    # flask-sqlalchemy
    db.init_app(app)

    # flask-mail
    mail.init_app(app)

    login_manager.setup_app(app)

    #event
    EventClass()

    #report
    Report()

    #search
    Search()

    #profile
    Profile_route()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    blueprints = DEFAULT_BLUEPRINTS
    configure_blueprints(app, blueprints)
    configure_app(app)
    configure_extensions(app)
    configure_auth()
    configure_swagger(app)
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, request_handler=MyFancyRequestHandler)
```

So `@api.route("/")` is working when it tries to access it, but all route declared outside this file (EventClass, Route, Search, ...) seems to be unaccessible. When I try to add another route to `main.py`, the route becomes accessible.

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

UPDATE:

If I run my `flask` app alone like this `python3 main.py` every route are available.

Comment: Hi, I finally figure out my mistake. it was just due to a bad architecture so the class were never called and init.

Comment: Hey! @Keuha I'm facing similar issues. What did you do, so that the classes were called and initialised?

Comment: hey @darkdefender27 It's been a while now, all I remember was to have paid attention to the import. The architecture of my project by this time was wrong and so only main.py was called and init. Making good usage of `__init__.py` might help you to solve your problem, it solves mine :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.